# C++ / Qtcreator /UPDATE data base

Tags: c++, sql, qt, interface, qt5

Hello everyone i'm working in a graphical interface application and i face a problem when i want to edit my database.

```
void livraisonDialog::on_editBtn_clicked()
{
    int CIN = ui->cin->text().toInt();
    QString NOM_LIVREUR = ui->nomLivreur->text();
    QString ADRESSE =  ui->adresse->text();
    int TEL_LIVREUR =  ui->telLivreur->text().toInt();
    QString DIPLOME =  ui->diplome->text();

QSqlQuery qry;

qry.prepare("UPDATE LIVRAISONS SET (CIN,NOM_LIVREUR,ADRESSE,TEL_LIVREUR,DIPLOME)"
            "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)"
            "WHERE CIN=?;"
            );

        qry.addBindValue(CIN);
        qry.addBindValue(NOM_LIVREUR);
        qry.addBindValue(ADRESSE);
        qry.addBindValue(TEL_LIVREUR);
        qry.addBindValue(DIPLOME);

        if(qry.exec()){

            QMessageBox::information(this,"Done", "information Updated");
        }else{
            QMessageBox::information(this,"ERROR", "information not UPDATED");
        }
```

}

Comment: Did you see this: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#lastError?  Took me 30 seconds to find it via google.  (Also, I'm no expert but I don't think you have enough calls to `addBindValue`).

Answer (score 0):

You are using a wrong query, the right update query is like this:

```
update table set column1 = 'value1', column2 = 'value2' where condition
```